# Memory leak in a haskell program

Tags: haskell, memory-management, garbage-collection

I've been trying to read and index a set of links and wikipedia abstracts with a haskell program. The aim is to

1. Read one line from the file
2. Parse it
3. Hash and index some parts of the line, along with the offset into the file so I can find it later

The problem is that my program is very slow and uses large amounts of memory. I've done some profiling and I know most of the time (~50%) is spent in garbage collection. I've tried everything I could think of to get to what I have now, including:

1. ST monad stuff with Data.Map as the storage
2. Using hashed values as keys, rather than keeping around entire bytestrings
3. Using seq and deepseq to try to prevent lazy allocation
4. Parsing line by line instead of hoping that lazyness would make a list of parsed lines space and time efficient
5. Using immutable hashmaps rather than Data.Map
6. Using mutable hashmaps

Code, data, profiling output and compilation stuff: https://gist.github.com/ririw/8205284

Thanks!

Comment: These lines look dubious to me: `let parsed = parseOnly linkLineParser line in parsed 'par' case (parseOnly linkLineParser line) of`, you should change that be more like popAbstract where the case is over `parsed`. I think you're on to something there with evaluating the NTEntries fully. (SO comments don't let me format it very well)

Comment: Ah good catch, I guess I changed the abstract one and forgot to do the link one. But this still doesn't fix it. I think I've missed some fundamentally important part of how memory allocation works or how I'm supposed to handle the data which might prevent the GC having to move so much around.

Comment: While I can't help you on the performance aspect, I can recommend http://hackage.haskell.org/package/swish-0.9.0.11/docs/Swish-RDF-Parser-N3.html for easy parsing

Comment: The surprising thing to me is that `resourceName` does 27% of allocation.  Interestingly when I run the program, `link` also does 23% of allocation.  Is the profiler output for exactly the program written in the gist?  Otherwise I don't understand the difference.  Anyway, it seems `takeWhile` and `skipWhile` do a lot of allocation.  Perhaps an `attoparsec` or `bytestring` expert can help.

Comment: I think I must have accidentally put up an old profiler run. I fixed this problem by switching from using `(.*>) :: ByteString -> Parser a -> Parser a` to using `string :: ByteString -> Parser ByteString` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to reduce the memory use by 100MB or so on my test set (the first 400K lines of the dbpedia links dataset, available at http://downloads.dbpedia.org/3.9/en/wikipedia_links_en.nt.bz2).

I did this by switching to the io-streams library which seems to have solved some of the issues with lazyness.

You can see the new solution at https://gist.github.com/ririw/8207250

On a 7574825 line dataset it does ok, and the memory usage ticks up in the way I'd expect a hash table to tick up as it filled itself and shuffled things around (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFwpV.jpg). Of course, that might also be the io-streams buffers doing the same thing.

It still uses a lot of memory :(, but I think has solved the lazyness/io issue

Comment: Still 17% of allocation done in `resourceName` which  still surprises me.  I don't see why it has to allocate at all.